# Will all programs run the same if moved to D drive?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, filesystems

My D drive has 931 GB and my C drive only has 221 GB and I'm running out of space. Will it be safe to use something like AOMEI Backupper and move everything to my D drive or are there programs I must keep on the C drive?

Comment: Your "C drive" is likely a SSD and your "D drive" is likely a HDD. If so then NO, they will run much slower.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But would I prevent from running out of space and what will I do with all that storage in my D Drive?

Comment: 221GB is plenty for Windows 10 and same software. Personal files like movies, music, projects, etc. that use a lot of space should go to the secondary drive. This is a proper way to use the space. Games also use a lot of space but should run in the faster drive. If 221GB isn't enough I would be getting a bigger one, not moving software to a HDD.

Comment: Those **may** work but it highly depends on the program and how it works.

Comment: Have a look at your personal files which you probably can move without even touching any "backup" software. Moving installed software may or may not break it depending on the software. Some are resilient others are not as they might have full paths in configuration files and the registry. Most game launchers allow you to move games, check their options if it's mostly games.